# Like to know the time complexity of this code snippet in Java

Tags: java, time-complexity

I would like to know the time complexity of the following code snippet,

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("myfile.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

for (long i = 0; i < n-1; i++ ) {
   br.readLine();       
}
System.out.println("Line content:" + br.readLine());
br.close();
fr.close();
```

Edit: I would like to say, n = a constant number, e.g. 100000

Comment: It appears to be O(n) unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complexity is O(n) but that doesn't tell you much because you don't know how much time each `readLine()` needs.

Calculating the complexity doesn't make much sense when individual operations have a very variable runtime behavior.

In this case, the loop is very cheap and will not contribute much to the runtime of the whole program. The loading from disk, on the other hand, will contribute very much to the runtime but it's hard to say without statistical information about the average number of lines per file and the average length of a line.

Comment: Say now the file size is now 2GB.
Will the complexity still remaiin O(n), if I do a string comparison say for e.g. if (br.readline().equals("myname")) inside the loop?

Comment: Yes, because this is a constant time operation (comparison with a constant). In reality, the runtime does depend on the result of `readline()` but O() complexity calculations allow for some leeway. Think of it this way: Over the whole file, there will be an average how much time `readline()` takes. So the runtime can be calculated as `average-time-per-readline * N` where the left part is "constant" for each file. Constants in complexity become `1` so you end up with `O(1*N)` or `O(N)`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very simple case, but here's how to find the time complexity. The same method can be applied for more complex algorithms.

For the following portion of code (and regardless of the complexity of `readline()`)

```
for (long i = 0; i < n-1; i++ ) {
   br.readLine();       
}
```

`i = 0` will be executed **(n-1)** times, `i < n-1` will be executed **n** times, `i++` will be executed **n-1** times, and `br.readline();` will be executed **n-1** times.

this gives us n-1+n+n-1+n-1 = **4*n-3**. This is proportional to `n`, so the complexity is **O(n)**.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "time complexity", but it would appear that it's performance is linear (AKA O(n)) with the size of the file it reads from.

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity of reading an entire file should be `O(N)` where `N` is the size of the file.

However, proving this would be difficult, given the amount of software that is involved.  You have got the Java code in the `main` method, the Reader stack (including the Charset decoder) and the JVM.  Then you have the code in the OS.  Then you have to take into account file buffering in kernel memory, file system organizations, disk seek times, etcetera.

(It is not meaningful to just consider *just* the time taken by the application.  We can safely predict that component of the total time taken will be dominated by the other components.)

And, as Aaron says the complexity measure is not going to be a reliable predictor of the actual file read time.

Comment: I would say `n` is the size looked for which may be much smaller or larger than N (the size of the file)

Comment: Unless you are postulating N to be a non-linear function of the file size, this won't alter the computational complexity.

Comment: Agreed. You might be looking for header entries which would change how you define `n`.

Answer (score 1):

The readLine() function has to scan every character of the input up to the next newline. This should be O(N), where N is the number of bytes in the first n lines (which you read). Using a buffered reader does not reduce algorithmic complexity, it just reduces the number of actual IO calls needed to read a given number of bytes (a good thing, since IO calls are expensive). In this case, the only way that would change things is if the buffer's read size was much larger than the total number of bytes you were going to read.